# Is there a way to prevent a text log file from getting locked?

Tags: c#, logging, text-files

We were writing our reporting logs to a database but a couple times our reports failed because the database was unavailable. We decided to switch to writing our logs to a text file, thinking that it would always work but I've had the write fail several times due to the .txt file being locked by another process.

Is there a way to prevent the text file from getting locked? If not I don't see the advantage to using a text file for logging purposes.

Comment: Why not use both database and log files? Most logging frameworks support this.

Comment: Wouldn't that just add 2 points of failure instead of one? These are custom reports created from scratch in c# so we can log it however we want.

Comment: Even if you log to file you can run out of disk space, so you need to take resiliency into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "NLog" or "SeriLog" to write logs into a file. Then use "ELK Stack" with "FileBeat" to transfer your logs from file to db. It is one of the best practices because:

1- You have your last logs inside log files. (So if you lose your db connection you
will see the root-cause)

2- You have all of your logs integrated inside a single db.

3- You can prettify and format your log files with Logging frameworks.

4- You can roll your log files to avoid huge log file generation.

5- You can separate your cross-cutting concerns (for example logging, log-cleaning, multiple-destination-logging and so on) from the core business of your application.

6- etc <3

Comment: Anytime <3. I will be glad if you mark it as correct answer (If you achieve your goals _

Comment: Thanks Amir, that looks like the way to go. Only downside is I have to learn how to do it. :)